# Подмена входящего номера

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip

Можно ли в звонках по SIP менять номер, чтобы на пользовательском телефоне вместо входящего номера светилось название компании, так же, как это делается во многих SMS-рассылках?

Comment: эту возможность уточняйте у своего сип провайдера, т.к со своей стороны Вы не сможете подменить номер, если Вы его подмените то звонок просто не уйдет через провайдера

Answer (score 1):

Для звонков входящих из ТфОП (от провайдера) вы это сделать сможете.
Для звонков в ТфОП (от вашей системы в сторону провайдера) вы это сможете сделать только по договорённости с провайдером и при наличии у него технической возможности.